# jquery set the value of a input not working

Tags: jquery, html, grails

I'm creating an app in grails in which I display a table with album and song details. What I'm trying to do is if someone clicks the 'purchase' button it's supposed to send the item's id and type ('Song' or 'Album') to a form with hidden inputs that is part of a confirmation modal. The problem is that when the 'purchase' button is pressed only the type gets sent to the corresponding 'type' input in the form and the 'id' input remains blank. Here's where it gets weird; I have a delete button that uses the exact same modal html code and button that triggers the modal and it works perfectly. Anyway, here's my code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Modal html:

```
<div id="confirmModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Purchase?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure you want to buy this item?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <g:form action="myColl" name="addForm">
                    <input type="text" id="itemId" name="itemId" value=""/>
                    <input type="text" id="itemType" name="itemType" value=""/>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                    <input  class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Yes"/>
                </g:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Button html:

```
<g:if test="${item.type == 'Album'}">
    <button type="button" onclick="$('#confirmModal').modal('show');
                                   $('#itemId').val(${item.id});
                                   $('#itemType').val('Album');" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Buy">✓</button>
</g:if>
<g:elseif test="${item.type == 'Song'}">
    //The exact same code as above with the only difference being $('#itemType').val('Song')
</g:elseif>
```

Note that I copied all this code from another file in my project in which everything works perfectly.

Comment: At least show the rendered HTML. It'd also be easier to debug if you had an external JS function that did this; then you could set a breakpoint and experiment.